# Can I Register and Host multiple Remote Event Receivers using the same Azure Web App URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app, azure, remote-event-receiver

I have the following question on how many Azure Web Apps i need to create, for hosting 8 Remote Event Receivers? Where In my case i have 8 Remote Event Receivers, which have been developed as Provider Hosted Apps. I want to deploy these 8 Remote Event Receivers inside Azure, but i am now sure how many Azure Web Apps i need create?

For example each Azure Web App will have a url such as `https://123******.azurewebsites.net`. Here is the settings for an Azure Web App, inside my Azure subscription account :-

[image]

Then when I register my App inside my site collection (using `/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx` page), i will provide the Azure Web App URL inside the App Damion field, as follow:-

[image]

So do i need 8 Azure Web Apps URLs (8 different App Domains), to register and host my Remote Event Receivers? Or i can use the same Azure Web App url to register multiple Remote Event Receivers?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can - an event receiver is just an endpoint and a web app can have any number of these.

The App model is what's tripping you up as it's not very well thought out and doesn't scale well to real world scenarios such as this.  You can in fact use event receivers without using the App model at all. I wrote a blog post partly inspired by people's frustrations with remote event receivers on this site. Have a look if you'd like: https://derekgusoff.wordpress.com/2017/11/08/remote-event-receivers-youre-all-doing-it-wrong/

Comment: to be honest dealing with Remote Event Receivers is the worst experience i have ever faced. from debugging to deploying.. now i have already read your link which looks great, but the problem is that in my case i have many synchronous events such as (adding,editing, etc) since i need to check some conditions before proceeding with the Edit/Create operations.. so that why i chose to have Remote Event Receivers, instead of following your appraoch. so back to my original question. now i did a test of hosting 2 RERs inside the same Azure Web App url, where inside Azure

Comment: >> i created a new Web App >> i got a url as follow `https://test200.azurewebsites.net/`.. now i developed 2 RERs, then when i register my first RER using the `/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx` page inside my site collection, i entered the url  `test200.azurewebsites.net/` inside the "App domain"field, then my first RER worked well. after that i repeated the same steps for the second RER, after that the second RER works well, but the first RER stopped working..

Comment: now i am pretty sure that i am doing something wrong because both RERs will have the same `<StartPage>~remoteAppUrl/?{StandardTokens}</StartPage>
    <InstalledEventEndpoint>~remoteAppUrl/Services/AppEventReceiver.svc</InstalledEventEndpoint>
    <UninstallingEventEndpoint>~remoteAppUrl/Services/AppEventReceiver.svc</UninstallingEventEndpoint>` inside the `app manifest.xml`+ they do have the same `AppEventReceiver.svc` file .. so logically speaking 2 different things can not be deployed under thet same url..

Comment: so not sure how i can deploy 2 RERs using the same Azure Web App url? what i need to change exactly? the `<StartPage>` url or the `<InstalledEventEndpoint>` url ??

Comment: To create a new RER in an existing web project, add a new WCF service, inherit from IRemoteEvent, implement the processRequest method, and register it via PowerShell or CSOM. The app model is the thing your struggling with.  The app model is what's forcing this "one event receiver" pattern. Remote Event Receivers themselves are really easy, it's the App Model that's causing all this frustration.

Comment: Here's another brilliant article on using Remote Event Receivers outside a provider hosted app. http://spblog.net/post/2017/09/09/Using-SharePoint-Remote-Event-Receivers-with-Azure-Functions-and-TypeScript

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. Now just to make sure i got your point correctly. Now when i create my first provider hosted app (to implement RER) inside VS, it mainly created an MVC web application, which have a “Services” folder, and under this folder i got a AppEventReceiver.svc file. Then i deploy this provider hosted app inside Azure web app. Now when i want to create my second RER, should i inside visual studio, create another MVC web application? Or i only need to create a WFC? If i only need to create a WFC, then where i can add the AppManifest.xml ?

Comment: or i will only have one `appManifext.xml` for all the RERs? since they are all inside the same Web application? I cannot find any documentation regarding this.. the situation looks horrible when it comes to RER… as the tutorials just show the same steps of creating very basic RER..
second point regarding your link http://spblog.net/post/2017/09/09/Using-SharePoint-Remote-Event-Receivers-with-Azure-Functions-and-TypeScript i am not sure why on MSDN documentation they did not mention this appraoch,, and all the documentation will create Provider hosted app to implement RER..

Comment: You can just create another WCF service and implement it, and deploy to the same web app. I agree, the documentation is horrible for remote event receivers. This site probably gets 15 or 20 questions a week from people just as confused as you at the approach. The app, appmanifest, and all that other garbage is what's tripping you up. It just doesn't support what you're trying to do. All you need is an endpoint and a registration.

Comment: first of all thanks a lot for your replies, they are really helpful, and i start seeing the light at the end of the tunnel ... so you mean first step i create and deploy my Provider Hosted App, which contain a single WCF (single RER), into an Azure Web App. now if i want to deploy additional RER, i do not have to create another Provider Hosted App, i just create a WCF, and deploy it inside the same Azure Web APP?is this correct? second point, if my first point is correct, then i think in this case having all RERs inside single Provider Hosted App,

Comment: means that all the RERs will be sharing the same `AppManifest.xml` and hence the same Permission settings, also i think in this case when i add the Provider Hosted app inside my related site collection/s all the RERs will get added.. is this correct? third point, so can i conclude that if my RERs or part of my RERs share the same Permission settings and will be activated on the same site collection/s, then i can add them inside the same Provider Hosted App (the same Azure Web App)?

Comment: while if the RERs have unique permission settings and will get added inside different site collections then it is better to have them on separate Provider hosted apps and so deployed on different web app? is my understanding valid, on the above three points?

Comment: can you advice on my above comments?